# Error signing Ad Hoc android APK: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I was signing the android part of my Xamarin Shared project. I created an archive using the archive for publishing button.

I had previously uploaded this app using the same signing certificate and was uploading to get an update out to alpha in the google play store. I had also previously used the same Package name. I switch between package names sometimes, so I first signed a version with a slightly different package name, which seemed to work fine. Except that I couldn't upload to the google play store because I forgot to change the version and had used the wrong package name.

So I went back and changed the package name and version. And ended up with the following error while signing the archive:
startIndex cannot be larger than length of string
Parameter name: startIndex

I assume it has something to do with the package name or version. After a quick stack overflow search I only found one possible fix, which mentioned a period to many in the package name. So I double checked the package name, but there was nothing wrong there (as far as I know). I did a double check on the version as well.

Anyone have any experience in dealing with an issue like this?

Comment: The fix for this issue was in the android manifest: Some of the permissions still mentioned another package name. Changing the permission fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error on a codebase where the app previously had a different package name. There were no references to the old ackage name in the Android manifest.

To resolve the issue I had to manually delete my bin and obj folders for SparkPortable and Droid then Rebuild. Clean did not resolve the issue--only manual deletion.